# Unstable current source when reaching a certain threshold in current draw

Tags: power-supply, noise, current-source, stability, oscillation

I’m currently building a system for automated testing of ECUs. It consists of an ECU with regulated loads connected to its power outputs. The other IO of the ECU is connected to an IO expansion card. The regulated loads, IO expansion and the needed power supplies are controlled by a central PC, which also receives data from the ECU. See the image below for an overview.

[image: [Block diagram of the system]]

The regulated loads are based around a standard voltage controlled current source with a MOSFET, see the image below. In this schematic the gain is configured in such a way that an input of 1V results in 2A of current through the MOSFET. The labels coil- & coil+ are connected to the power output of the ECU. As these ECU outputs usually control a solenoid valve, **this is a PWM based output**.

[image: Current regulation schematic]

Everything worked well until we had to give a demonstration and the entire system was moved. Ever since there is the issue that when the regulated loads combined reach a certain current threshold the output of the power supplies becomes unstable. This in turn causes the regulation in the regulated loads to follow that instability. Depending on the setpoint of the load, this means a higher (and fluctuating) current or the MOSFET in the load to reach its saturation region, allowing tens of amps to flow. Which in turn trips the 24V PSU’s shirt circuit detection, thankfully. See image below for measurements of the instability.

[image: Oscilloscope measurements of PSU noise]

All measurements were done with AC coupling to isolate the noise. The top images are measurements of the output of the 24V PSU itself. The left one is during normal operation and the one on the right was made during the described fault situation. The image at the bottom is from an internal control signal of the connected electronic load. The measured signal is the signal that controls the current regulation which should have been a stable DC voltage for accurate control.

The design of the electronic load is custom, but acts like a resistive load. The interesting part is that the described behavior does not occur when using solenoids as loads. This makes we wonder if di/dt is too big when the output gets turned on, but at the same time this di/dt is the same for all outputs and the behavior doesn’t occur until a certain current threshold seems to be reached.

In my opinion two other things might be the cause as well. During the part in the PWM cycle where the output is low, the current regulation ramps up the gate voltage of the MOSFET as high as the opamp allows. When the PWM cycle goes high the MOSFET can’t be adjusted quickly enough, causing an overshoot. See image below. Perhaps this overshoot causes issues with the control logic in the 24V PSU, resulting in oscillation.

[image: Current overshoot due to PWM cycle]

The other possibility I could think if is based on the output filter of the 24V PSU. Assume this filter is an LC filter and is optimized for a high load. Having a low load connected changes the characteristics and causes a small range of frequencies to be amplified instead of attenuated. See the image below, this is just a generic example and not using actual values of the system.

[image: Comparison of filter gain]

I have contacted the PSU manufacturer and their recommendation is to place a few capacitors of different values near the regulated loads, acting like a filter. My own idea was to place filter capacitors near the 24V PSU itself. I haven’t tested these ideas yet, as even normal values (0.1 and 45 uF) would give a lot of current spiking during the charge and discharge of the capacitor caused by the PWM cycle. Using an application note about decoupling capacitors to calculate the actually recommended capacitors results in values in the tens of milli-farad range, resulting in even bigger current spikes.

Another interesting fact is that replacing the used switch-mode PSU with a linear PSU solves the issue. The problem is that a linear PSU that is able to supply the required 100A for a full system is way outside my budget.

**TL:DR**: A perfectly working system containing regulated loads stopped working after being moved. When the load reaches a certain (current) threshold the PSU output gets very noise, ruining the current regulation. This could be caused by:

- Disruption of the PSU control logic due to di/dt being too high.
- By overshoot of the current regulation during the change from low
  to high in the PWM cycle.
- The design of the filter in the PSU, causing amplification of some frequencies when connecting a low load.

The PSU manufacturer recommends filter capacitors near the loads. But I highly doubt this is the solution and they seem to cause large current spikes when (dis-)charging during the PWM cycle.

Does anyone have any pointers what might be causing this issue and what might be possible solutions?

Comment: when moved, how was the cabling changed? what GROUND nodes were altered?

Comment: it may be caused by external influences, such as powerline noise, RF interference, etc.  .... are you able to move the equipment back to its original location?

Comment: Does each load have its own power supply? How is the CAN bus interfaced to it? Which switches (high, low, both) have PWM applied to them? The 24V power supply is simulating a battery, right?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf There was no cabling changed connection-wise, the only possibility is that they have moved a little bit. There were no ground nodes changed, at least not on purpose and I haven't been able to find any accidental changes. There were no changes to any part of system, accept its physical location.

Comment: @jsotola The system has been moved to its origin location, this didn't solve the issue. I have experimented with both creating twisted pairs or adding space between the wires that carry the high current PWM signals

Comment: @BruceAbbott Half of the loads have their control logic powered by one 12V PSU, the other half by another 12V PSU. The 24V PSU powers the ECU, which in turn uses its low- and high-side switches to pass this through to all the loads. Of these switches only the high-side uses PWM.

The 24V PSU simulates the entire power delivery in a very simple way, it only controls its on/off state and a steady voltage level. It is possible the simulate fluctuations, but this is outside of the scope at the moment.

As for your question about the CAN interface, do you mean electrically or bus-topology?

Comment: then change SOMETHING, anything, everything, to learn what affects the oscillation at 350,000 Hz. And set the scope speed to 10US/division, to verify the oscillation at 350,000Hz.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf I have experimented with both creating twisted pairs or adding space between the wires that carry the high current PWM signals. The only effect it had was a change in amplitude of the noise, not the frequency.

Comment: _"about the CAN interface, do you mean electrically or bus-topology?"_ I mean electrically. Please show the _actual_ circuit of the electronic load including how the CAN signal gets converted to an analog voltage, where the 'internal control signal' is, and the power and ground connections. Also the physical layout (PCB etc.)

Comment: What is the reason for having a constant current load, and what is the maximum current that it will be set to for testing?

Comment: @BruceAbbott The load is actually used to present a constant 'resistance' to the ECU. It's limited to 4A@12V and 2A@24V (or 50W).

As the design is proprietary and divided over 7 pages I can't show the entire design. The CAN signal goes via a transceiver to a MCU. After some calculations it uses its built-in DAC to control the actual current regulation hardware. The question has been updated to include the schematic of the actual design.

As for the layout, it's basically impossible to give you a usable image. It's 4 layers and the resolution would be huge to have readable labels.

Comment: Getting there... where in the circuit is the 'internal control signal' from which you got the 3rd scope trace? I can't find a datasheet for your FET. Can you provide a link to it?

Comment: @BruceAbbott The internal control signal was measured at testpoint TP6 (top left). The datasheet of the FET is available at https://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/discrete_mosfets/littelfuse_discrete_mosfets_n-channel_linear_ixt_80n075_datasheet.pdf.pdf